# Notation of Projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
Hello everybody.
Im sorry if this is a stupid question, but I don't know the answer myself and would like to know it.

**What does the notation $\mathbb{P}_{a,b}^1$ mean?**

I saw this for the first time in the Wikipedia article about $\Spec(-)$ in the section about global $\Spec(-)$.
I couldn't find this notation anywhere else.

Thank You for Your help,

kindly SDIGR

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$Hello and thanks for pointing this out. However I think I did point out that I saw this notation in the Wikipedia article about $\Spec(-)$ in the section about Global $\Spec(-)$. Should I give a link?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Proj}{Proj}$The only reasonable thing that I can think about is $\mathbb{P}_{a,b}^n\colon=\Proj(k[a,b][x_0,\cdots,x_n])$. The same notation is also used here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proj_construction#Global_Proj]

Comment: a link is a great idea

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I will do better in future :).

Comment: I would guess it refers to $\mathbb P^1$ with homogeneous coordinates $(a:b)$.